# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> InAppBrowser]:

Tags: ionic3

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> InAppBrowser]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> InAppBrowser]:

Answer (score 1):

add `InAppBrowser` in your providers' array in the `app.module.ts` file